# Can I emulate TRIM by writing all zeros?

Tags: ssd, usb-flash-drive, trim

Before an SSD sector<sup>1</sup> was ever written to, it looks like all filled with zeros.

So, if I write all zeros to a sector, for the purpose of functionality, it will look just like a free one. Thus the controller has a technical possibility to treat it as such. My limited knowledge of IC architecture says that hardware-wise, slowdown from a circuit testing for all zeros would probably be negligible, if any at all.

The question is: does any flash/SSD controller actually implement this or anything similar?

It looks even more applicable to flash memory storage connected via interfaces that don't have the TRIM command, like USB.

In the answers posted so far, a few people outlined possible show-stopper issues. Yet they all turned out to be non-issues. Unless there's evidence those really are serious problems, please do not authoritatively claim they are but rather honestly say you're only hypothesizing that.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>A logical sector i.e. what the host sees.</sub>

Comment: SSDs will wear out quickly if you write to every single sector.  Each cell has a limited number of times that it can be written to, and after that the cell is too slow to be useful.  If you have security reasons to "secure erase" the drive, then know that most SSDs are overprovisioned, so that there are physical cells left to spare.  Thus, someone who can use a vendor utility to access every single cell might have access to data you thought was "securely erased".

Comment: Sounds like you are asking whether some controller would do garbage collection by checking whether a *logical* block contains (to be less ambiguous, *reads*) all zero? (Like, auto-TRIM it if that's the case?)

Comment: @TomYan It's even easier. It only needs to be checked on an incoming write command. If the data operand is all zeros, no writing is done and the logical block is unmapped instead.

Comment: I've heard of controllers that would be *smart* enough to ignore zero filling after it exceeds certain contiguous length. I would assume (part of) the logical blocks would be in a state that is equivalence as TRIM'd.

Comment: @TomYan I read that top gun SSDs (like Samsung PRO/EVO) compress data on the fly to achieve even faster read/write speeds - naturally, a chunk of zeros compresses really well.

Comment: "So, unless there's evidence those really are serious problems, answers authoritatively claiming they are (rather than only hypothesizing that) are not acceptable." - They are acceptable from a community perspective.  They might just not answer your question.  I caution you from using verbiage like "not acceptable", as a question author, you want as many people willing to write an answer as possible, negative verbiage can chase people who might know the answer to your question away.

Comment: I’m VTC as too broad because there are too many flash controller types. You need to seriously narrow down the scope of this question. Either way, Super User is not a research service.

Comment: @DanielB there are not so many distinctive techniques that SSDs use and they are typically mentioned in tech papers/reviews/etc. i.e. don't require firmware-level knowledge of specific models. Controllers only vary in details of their implementation which are of no concern here.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that **this appears to be the case at least for some SSDs***. I've tested this empirically for an older Kingston SSD (see below), and another person [reported](https://superuser.com/questions/740803/trim-vs-writing-zeros-the-same#comment2797792_740827) this to work for both a 2012 Sandisk SSD and a 2015 Samsung SSD.
*As pointed out in the comments and in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1830443) answer, the data below does not* prove *that the firmware of the tested SSD treats writing zeros in the exact same way it treats a TRIM command; it's also possible that it e.g. applies compression which in practice has a similar, but non-identical effect. Hence a smoking-gun result is still outstanding and would require lower-level analysis of the hardware (or retrieving and directly analysing the firmware).*

Due to data recovery from a dead laptop, I had a spare Kingston SATA 256GB SSD (RBU-SNS8152S3256GG2) inside an M.2-to-USB3 adapter which I decided to re-use for an RPi. Unfortunately, it turned out that the adapter does not support TRIM and that write performance was already significantly reduced from previous usage (~50MiB/s for sequential writes as per `fio` and even less for small random writes, even though zfs compression was accidentally still active, hence real speeds were even lower).

Trying to avoid buying another M.2-to-USB3 enclosure, I've decided to test whether writing all zeros to the SSD would restore the performance (and avoid excessive wear due to write amplification). It worked nicely, with sequential write speeds increasing to ~230MiB/s and 8KiB random writes around 110MiB/s (again tested via `fio` on a zfs dataset with compression on, for comparability with earlier results).

The explicit command to write zeros to the SSD was as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk/by-id/<device_id> bs=1M status=progress &> <filename>.log
```

While not being a proper benchmark and thus to be taken with a grain of salt, the first `dd` run itself had the following write speeds, showing the reduced and inconsistent performance:
[image: first dd run]

After performing various tests incl. running `dd` a few times more (with random-valued & zero-valued input) and giving the SSD time to perform garbage collection, I did a final zero-valued `dd` run to refresh the SSD before putting it to use, resulting in the following write speeds:
[image: final dd run]

Ignoring the few outliers which were probably caused by other processes interfering (computer was not idle during test), it now looks rock solid and mirrors the significantly better results from `fio`.

* I've also observed this behaviour for several older external SMR drives from Western Digital that do not support TRIM (at least not via the USB connection) and which were almost unusable after several years, with even sequential writes being excruciatingly slow and huge latency spikes; writing all zeros to those drives with `dd` fully refreshed them.

Comment: Not convincing. First of all rule of thumb answer is not TRIM =/= write zeros as it depends on controller actively detecting zeros (yes and I know some actually do, it's manufacturer described behavior). So you can not rely on it. Second we don't see what would have happened if you had written random data. I have seen read performance of SSDs improve after simply read existing data and write it back, seemingly simply fresh data being written accomplishes this whether it's zeros or something else.

Comment: For fun I experimented with methods to try detect if NAND flash was 'trimmed' or unmapped or if zeros were written to it. Since unmapped NAND memory isn't actually read while zeroed NAND is, the idea was, since reading NAND requires energy, we may be able to detect a difference in power consumption, and this turns out to be the case: https://imgur.com/a/hg7VCii. I wouldn't go as far to call this scientific, my equipment isn't and I have only tried on one device.

Comment: And this image demonstrates effects of refreshing already present data (so not writing zeros): https://imgur.com/a/87o79wO. (compare 1 - 3)

IOW, you can not conclude the your observed effect is due to the drive treating zeros in same manner as unmapping LBA addresses from actual NAND real-estate as same effect can be observed after refreshing data.

Comment: Joep van Steen has a point -- but it's fixable. Just need more data -- e.g. the performance of random reads of a drive filled with zeros vs a drive filled with random data. Maybe SMART also says something relevant (e.g. maybe the "total LBAs written" value does not increase if you overwrite zeros with more zeros).

Comment: _Randomly_ filling the drive with random data and with zeros should affect _sequential_ read speed. If zeros are allocated, there'll be no difference in speed. If they are trimmed, reading zeros will be faster. Probably the faster the larger chunks you read at a time.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen 1) "So you can not rely on it." Fully agreed, it certainly depends on the firmware. 2) "I have seen read performance of SSDs improve after simply read existing data and write it back" Note that my answer talks about write performance, which should be mainly impacted by TRIM or lack thereof (due to write amplification). 3) "imgur.com/a/87o79wO" What is shown on the y-axis? The label is unfortunately not readable due to limited resolution.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev "Logical Sectors Written" increases and sequential read speed is ~365MiB/s in either case (which might well be the max. speed of the involved M.2-to-USB3 adapter or the USB-C travel hub). While I wouldn't take either result as strong evidence, I've updated my answer to reflect the absence of conclusive evidence. Unfortunately I don't have hardware at hand to drill down further.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I emulate TRIM by writing all zeros?

No.

Here's how flash works:

- Unwritten flash is all 1's, and writes pull down the 1's to 0's.
- Flash is written in a quantity of bytes known as a *page*, 2048 bytes being an example of a page size.  (There is also a small amount of data - 64 bytes or so, that is also part of that page where ECC information can be stored)
- What if you want to change 0's back to 1's.  You can't unless you erase the page.
- When you erase flash - which flips all the bits back to 1's if the page is not damaged, the quantity of bytes you can erase (the *eraseblock* size to borrow from Linux terminology) is typically bigger than the page size.  128k being an example of an eraseblock size.
- Erasing takes a lot more time than just writing to a page.

So, because:

- SSDs pretend they are standard hard drives to the host.  Standard hard drives work on 512 byte sectors (called LBAs and numbered 0 to the capacity of the drive divded by 512), not 2048 or any other size;
- and the SSD firmware has to do a lot of fakery in the background since there really isn't 512 byte places to store the data like on a spinning hard drive;
- and writing to a page that doesn't need to be erased is faster than erasing it, then writing to it.

SSDs maintain something called an LBA to PBA table.  The operating system, for example, tells the SSD to write to LBA 20, but it might really go into something like "Flash chip 2 page 56".  This is maintained in the LBA to PBA table.

The SSD firmware will try to direct writes to fresh pages and avoid erasing unless necessary.  If no unwritten pages are available, it will have to shuffle things around and do a read/maybe write somewhere else/eraseblock/write a bunch of stuff back cycle.

So the LBA to PBA table can be completely random.

TRIM tells the SSD that it can remove entries from this table (or mark as "LBA not written to yet") and actually erase some flash, and have it available for fast writes in the future.

So this is why writing all 0x00's or 0xFF's isn't equivalent.  Only TRIM tells the firmware it's OK to not track things in that table and consider flash unused - and erase it in preparation for new writes.

Writing all 0x00's or 0xFF's results in a full LBA-to-PBA table that is tracking a data it thinks you are using and things will remain slow due to the need for it to shuffle things around and read/erase/rewrite.

Comment: Yet another non-issue. Since the described "special write" only affects the "LBA to PBA table", it doesn't matter that pages/erase blocks are larger than logical sectors - nothing would actually be written to NAND. The only problem is a block would have to be marked as "partially free" - but TRIM also accepts a set of logical block ranges (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267244/ata-trim-specification/3267568#3267568 for a spec link), so the drive has to be able to cope with such a situation anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't put it past some crappy firmwares to actually write the 0's to the flash.  You have no way of knowing what the firmware is doing unless you have the source code, compiled it, and installed it on the device yourself - or the firmware maker specifically warrants the specific behaivor.  You might be able to discern true behavior by measuring timing of commands, though.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is likely not, and **if** you can do that it would be only because your controller explicitly detects zeroed blocks and trim them (I'm not even sure if any controller does this but afaik some VM implementation can detect zeroed blocks and trim them on the host OS).

All previous answers talk about flash format and the fact it starts with all bits set to 1's, but *that is completely besides the point*. Most controllers will return all *zeros* for trimmed/unallocated blocks (not all of them guarantees it IIRC!) and so the idea is that if you write 0's to a block, the controller might be able to detect it and trim the block rather than allocating and saving it.

I don't think there can be a clear *No* answer without looking at all major controller firmwares and see if any implement this feature, but if a controller can implement it without noticeable overhead it's definitely a plus as zeroed blocks will both be faster to write and extend the disk's life expectancy, not just with the saved block write but also by leaving more free blocks for wear leveling.

Answer (score 2):

### No and Yes.

---

TL;DR: TRIM is a command that is designed to inform the drive about LBA ranges it can set aside for garbage collection. While writing zeros can have this effect depending on how the firmware treats zero entropy data, in a worst case scenario it actually allocates entire LBA space leaving just over-provisioned space as wiggle room for the firmware, potentially increasing write amplification and thus wear - the exact opposite of what you're trying to accomplish.

---

**Simple answer**: No. TRIM is a **command** that in general causes a SSD drive to unmap LBA from PBA addresses. If such an unmapped sector is read the controller returns zeros without even reading the drive. Unmapped or stale sectors become available for the garbage collector that can then consolidate NAND blocks it can erase, after which space is available for the drive to write to.

Writing zeros is writing data and so writing zeros from LBA(min) to LBA(max) causes the entire LBA space to be mapped. Or at least this was how this worked and still works on older and perhaps cheaper, lower spec drives.

So while effect is or better appears the same when we read from the drive as reading from a zero-filled drive, it is not actually the same.

---

I have done experiments that show a difference in power consumption between reading from a zeroed drive vs. a 'trimmed' drive: For reading actual zeros from the NAND the drive has to do actual work, provide power to charge-pumps to achieve required voltages to read the NAND cells.

[image]

---

**HOWEVER!**

1. As others suggested the SSD firmware may be clever enough to detect you're writing zeros and so may refrain from actually storing the zeros and instead make a 'note' in it's mapping tables that some LBA sector is having zeros written to it, so when the time comes you read the LBA sector the controller simply returns zero filled sectors.
2. Even if the controller does not apply above method, it may be compressing data ([example](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technology-briefs/ssd-520-tech-brief.pdf)). And so for writing zeros to entire LBA space the controller may only have to allocate a fraction of NAND real-estate to store the data.

The smart firmware makes sense and controllers with a dedicated compression unit too, as if the manufacturer can limit the amount of data written to a drive, it will live longer.

The effect of writing zeros to the drive will have a similar effect as TRIM if zeros are written to LBA space that previously contained data: Controller detects the zeros or can compress that to virtually nothing, which means the LBA space containing the original data can be unmapped (and made available to garbage collector) while it virtually has to assign no physical space to storing the zeros.

To further support this idea, a colleague of mine was recently researching the translation algorithm of a modern SSD and for this he wrote a pattern to the drive (0x77 bytes). He noticed the SSD was *not actually writing* by observing power consumption: To write data the voltage in the NAND needs to be increased, 'pumped up' even more than when reading. So these controllers appear to detect any low entropy data (not just zeros) and for example keep a table with 'place holder data' for LBAs that have zero entropy data written to them.

**So the longer answer is** that **it depends on the drive's controller and firmware**. The more modern the drive the better the chance the firmware will detect zeros/compress and so effect will be similar to TRIM.

**But you can not just assume a drive will work like this** and also you could argue if it does, **it's just a side effect** of foe example on-the-fly compression done by the controller.

Difference is that TRIM is quicker as no actual data transport from host to drive is required. And another difference is that **TRIM was sort of designed for what you want to do** and probably more predictable in behavior.

Comment: There's no arguing that TRIM is better. The purpose of asking was specifically to find out if writing zeros is a viable alternative when it's not available.

Comment: I answered that, didn't I? It depends on firmware and how it treats zeros: If it treats zeros as any other data, filling the drive with zeros is counter productive: TRIM would UNMAP all LBA space, zero filling would MAP all LBA space, so exact opposite of what TRIM would do. It seems you're not understanding the actual issues and mechanisms involved.

Comment: You did answer that. And it's quite clear that "it depends on firmware and how it treats zeros". So the real question boils down to if there's any evidence how exactly SSD controllers treat zeros. You gave evidence that the one you've examined (it'd help to write the model), that supports TRIM, does not treat them specially -- that's why I upvoted your answer.

Comment: I can not remember what SSD I tested with, but I tested only the hypothesis that it can be measured or difference could be detected whether/between the SSD is actually reading from NAND or firmware is merely returning zeros without actually accessing the NAND. For data recovery purposes and without needing to remove the NAND and dump it's contents. I don't care too much about upvotes and all, I simply was wondering if I got my message across and whether it was received correctly. And I added my answer because I think currently rewarded answer does  it demonstrate what it thinks it is.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I emulate TRIM by writing all zeros?

No.
The act of writing requires an erased sector, and then the actual write operation occurs.
The write operation is an indication to the SSD that this sector is in use (the opposite condition that you want with a real TRIM command).

> Before an SSD sector was ever written to, it looks like all filled with zeros.

Incorrect, and apparently your question is based on this faulty premise.
An erased sector is filled with bytes of 0xFF (all ones).

A format traditionally writes all zeros to every sector.

> So, if I write all zeros to a sector, for the purpose of functionality, it will look just like a free one.

No, it will not.
Beware that there are "free" sectors at the filesystem level, and "free" sectors at the SSD level.  In theory they should be the same set, but since the SSD has to be explicitly informed by the filesystem that a sector is "free" (with a TRIM comand), there are discrepancies.

**ADDENDUM**

> Thus the controller has a technical possibility to treat it as such. My limited knowledge of IC architecture says that hardware-wise, slowdown from a circuit testing for all zeros would probably be negligible, if any at all.
>
> The question is: does any flash/SSD controller actually implement this or anything similar?

No, because that would lead to unintended data loss.
Whenever a program wrote a sector of all zeroes (e.g. a memory image can have such blocks), your scheme would allow the SSD to discard that sector, since it would handle it as an unmapped sector, instead of a sector in use and allocated to a file.

Bottom line, your proposed scheme (using data content) does not work.
If you want to designate a sector as free or unused, then there's the TRIM command.
There is no substitute write operation.

Comment: `An erased sector is filled with bytes of 0xFF (all ones).`? Then where comes `RZAT` in ATA and `LBPRZ` in SCSI? (where the Z is zero)

Comment: @TomYan The zeroes that those commands return are not the result of reading the media. They are generated by the logic on the drive when you read "TRIM"d blocks.

Comment: @TomYan -- Documentation for flash chips clearly state that the erased state is all ones.  Documentation for SSD clearly indicate that the controller will *respond* with zeros for the data when that flag is set for a "free" (i.e. unmapped) LBA/sector.  This does not mean that the LBA/sector actually contains zeros, since that would actually hinder performance (i.e. it's not erased and ready for a write). See the last paragraph of Section 3.8.2 of http://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/ssd-fam/1200-ssd/en-us/docs/100708406b.pdf

Comment: @sawdust see my comment in David Schwartz's answer.

Comment: _> and apparently your question is based on this faulty premise._ You cannot be father from the truth. My question doesn't depend in the slightest on what exact pattern needs to be written. Also, by "appears to be filled with zeros", I mean that zeros are what is returned to the host - I'm pretty sure no (non-metadata) NAND reading is done in such case at all.

Comment: @sawdust Also, when it comes the logical block, if it reads zero, then it "contains" zero. That's why it was called "logical" block.

Comment: @sawdust Finally, I suggested that such "writes" can be handled in a special way, without actually erasing/overwriting any (non-metadata) blocks. It almost looks like you didn't read into my post at all before replying.

Comment: _Whenever a program wrote a sector of all zeroes... your scheme would allow the SSD to... handle it as an unmapped sector, instead of a sector in use and allocated to a file._ Ever heard of [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)? As long as the host reads from a specific logical sector exactly what it wrote to it earlier, it couldn't care less how the drive handles it internally. It's not like an unmapped _logical_ SSD sector can suddenly start to contain something other that zeroes, is it?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev *"As long as the host reads from a specific logical sector exactly what it wrote to it earlier, it couldn't care less how the drive handles it internally"* -- Not true.  I've worked on systems that have written zero-filled files to ensure that the sectors are accessible &  allocated, i.e. to guarantee that (re)writing that file will not generate an "out-of-space" error.   Note that "sparse" files should only be implemented at the filesystem level (which can define what is "not data"), and not at the storage device level.

Comment: @sawdust Good point about "out of space". But not applicable to SSDs 'cuz they guarantee they're able to hold the entire advertised capacity of data all at once. I never proposed to use all the properties of sparse files such as the property to be able to be larger than the available storage. Only the property that the chunks that are all zeros don't actually need to be stored.

Comment: This answer confuses sectors (as seen by the host side) and flash blocks (as seen by the flash controller on the stick). While erased (nand) flash reads back as all 1's, this has nothing to do with sectors presented to the OS. For the OS side, an unmapped sector and an all-zero sector are the same (other than possibly speed of access), and will not cause issues as wrongly claimed by this answer. Sparse files are a completely different concept and should not be mixed into this discussion - both mapped and unmapped sectors can cause a flash drive to run out of (internal) storage space.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, an erased SSD sector is filled with ones, not zeros. You are confusing SSD sectors (the actual physical sectors on the SSD that we want to trim) with disk sectors (the logical sectors the SSD presents to the file system after it's done with its management magic). Filling logical sectors with zero would untrim since it would force the SSD to allocate erased physical SSD sectors and fill them with zeros.

When a logical sector is trimmed, the SSD unmaps any physical sectors mapped to that logical sector. When it gets a chance, it erases them, which fills them with 1's. Once erased, they're added to a pool of erased physical sectors. The goal of trimming is to enlarge the pool of erased physical sectors.

When you read a logical sector that has no corresponding physical sector, the drive returns a page of zeroes. But it doesn't have to read any physical sector to do so, nor could it since no physical sectors are mapped.

See [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/file-ssd.pdf) for more details.

Comment: @RickBrant My point is, whether the physical sectors behind the scene are "one-filled" is out of the scope of the OP (neither do I think "one" is a good way putting it when you talks about the electronic level). What the OP needs to know is, the logical blocks read zero does not necessarily means any physical sector is freed. Otherwise he would naturally comes with question like, "can I emulate TRIM by one-filling". It was never about how a sector is filled but merely its state in the "logical block provisioning" sense.

Comment: @TomYan I don't agree with you. He wouldn't come back with a question like that because he knows reading at trimmed sector returns all zeroes. As for it being out of scope of the OP, understanding the difference between physical and logical sectors is critical to understanding what TRIM is and does and why writing isn't a replacement for it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I know how TRIM works. And exactly due to that, deduced a technically possible way to emulate it: such writes can be handled in a special way that does exactly what TRIM would do.

Comment: Trimmed sectors may not necessarily returns zero, not on all drives, that's why the RZAT/LBPRZ "bit" exists. It totally depends on the implementation of the TRIM on the drives. Sure it's a good thing to know what's the "reset" electronic state of a "SSD physical sector", but calling it one-filled and compare it against states on the logical block layer? I don't see how appropriate or correct it is.

Comment: @TomYan -- *"neither do I think "one" is a good way putting it when you talks about the electronic level"* -- Raw flash that has been erased will read as all ones.

Comment: "I know how TRIM works." - So why did you deduce if you fill the drive with 0's instead of 1's you would get what you want?

Comment: @Ramhound because _Before an SSD sector* was ever written to, it looks like all filled with zeros. (*A logical sector i.e. what the host sees.)_

Comment: @sawdust I never said it does not. The sentence you quoted was never about objecting that fact. It was about calling it "one(-filled)" is misleading, as if it is about writing ones to/through the logical sectors. That's why I prefer "reset", or whatever the "charge" is (positive/negative). More importantly, the "one-filled fact" doesn't matter here, because it would also be "one-filled" (electronic/physical sense) if you "one-filled" (logical sense, a.k.a. normal block writing) it, but it doesn't mean it is "unmapped" / "unused" / "trim'd".