# which year TRIM was first used on SSD’s?

Tags: ssd, storage

New here, so apologies if it has been asked before.

I was curious as to whether Its known when TRIM first started being implemented into SSD’s?

Comment: [What is TRIM exactly?](https://superuser.com/questions/308754/what-is-trim-exactly) takes it's dates from Wikipedia for different OS's

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)#Operating_system_support) on the subject shows the first implementation was in Linux in late 2008. That's confirmed by the Block section at [lwn.net's December 29, 2008 article](https://web.archive.org/web/20081229045802/http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_28#head-a1a9591f48fe0cf8fde1f0d1f637c7ae54ad0bfa), titled "Support discard requests on SSD devices to improve wear-leveling."